# How to get data from @html.encode() and pass to @html.editorfor()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)
```

Above this is in MVC 4 Razor view html Helper method control. it exists in `_Layout.cshtml` file and I want to get the User name from this Control and want to set it in html `HtmlHelper` method control which is below.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
```

But both views have their separate Models so how can I get User name and pass it into

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
```

and when I Click save button it should save in Database.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Add a property `UserName` to your view model(s)

Comment: How to get "date" please read it  as"Data" with mistake  I typed date.

Comment: You can always edit your own question :)